# issue with implementation of sbt from tutorial

Tags: sbt

I am running through the [SBT: The Missing Tutorial](https://github.com/shekhargulati/52-technologies-in-2016/blob/master/02-sbt/README.md) to get a better understanding of sbt. In the [Writing your own tasks](https://github.com/shekhargulati/52-technologies-in-2016/blob/master/02-sbt/README.md#writing-your-own-tasks) part of the tutorial the following code was written:

```
gitCommitCountTask := {
  val branch = Process("git symbolic-ref -q HEAD").lines.head.replace("refs/heads/","")
  val commitCount = Process(s"git rev-list --count $branch").lines.head
  println(s"total number of commits on [$branch]: $commitCount")
  commitCount
}
```

There is no clear indication of which directory or file this code should be added to. Can anyone point me in the right direction. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text above this code says:

> Creating a custom task is a two step process:
>
> - You have to define a `TaskKey` for your task
> - You have to provide the task definition
>
> To write our task we will first write `gitCommitCountTask` `taskKey`
>   in the `build.sbt` file

So both the task key and the task definition should be placed in the `build.sbt` file in the root of your project.